# JavaScript equivalent of ?? operator in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, undefined

Is there any equivalent of ?? operator as exists in C# in JavaScript to defeat 'undefined' checking? 
For example:

```
var count = something ?? 0;
```

Comment: `var count = (typeof something === 'undefined') ? 0 : something;` This is a more verbose version of @Zee's answer (arguably more secure).

Comment: @evolutionxbox: I think you have the values the wrong way around

Comment: @musefan you're right, I did.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use logical OR

```
var count = something || 0;
```

Comment: Be aware this will not work with booleans : `someflag || true` will return true if `someflag` is false

Comment: wouldn't this also fail with an int that is 0  ?

Comment: Yes, this check will give you bad results with anything on the left side of the operand that could legitimately be falsy. Zero is the obvious problem here, but in this case won't matter. I have been bitten by this so many times i try to avoid using it for anything other than comparing objects now.